# Find duplicate value and then merge all child elemens

Tags: xslt

```
My requirement is that I have an input xml like:
<position>
<positionseqno>1</positionseqno>
<tag1>123</tag1>
 <child1>abc</child1>
 <child2>def</child2>
</position>
<position>
<positionseqno>2</positionseqno>
<tag1>345</tag1>
 <child1>jkl</child1>
 <child2>mno</child2>
</position>
<position>
<positionseqno>3</positionseqno>
<tag1>123</tag1>
 <child1>qrs</child1>
 <child2>tyu</child2>
</position>
```

and I I need output xml like below:

```
<position>
    <positionseqno>1</positionseqno>
    <tag1>123</tag1>
     <child1>abc</child1>
     <child2>def</child2>
     <child1>qrs</child1>
     <child2>tyu</child2>
    </position>
    <position>
    <positionseqno>2</positionseqno>
    <tag1>345</tag1>
     <child1>jkl</child1>
     <child2>mno</child2>
    </position>
```

IN short within position tag, if tag1 has similar values like 123, then all child values of duplicate nodes should be under first tag1 and except first occurrence rest should be removed.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Have a look into muenchian grouping in XSLT

Comment: Thanks Saurav, I tried, but i am completely new to xslt. I ended up messing up things.

Comment: It would be great if anyone could provide me some working xslt. Thanks for all the help

Comment: You should at least show what you have tried so that we can help you in where you have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should mention what xslt version you are using.
Try out this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key match="position" name="caseMatch" use="tag1"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <channel>
      <xsl:for-each select="//position[count(. | key('caseMatch', tag1)[1]) = 1]">
        <position>
          <xsl:copy-of select="positionseqno"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="tag1"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('caseMatch', tag1)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='positionseqno' and local-name()!='tag1']" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </position>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </channel>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note I have my output set to xml. That is why channel node exists in my answer.